# Very strange "fake numbers" in terminal

Tags: c, numbers, numeric

I know images aren't usually the way of doing this, but I have a very strange.. error.. seems more like a hack than anything else.

I have a picture here that shows the code and output because it was the only way I could show what is happening. Somehow, I managed to enter numbers that look like numbers but don't act like them.  Their text is more square then real numbers, and that's the only difference I can find.  It's kind of freaking me out... I feel like I was being trolled.

Someone please tell me it was a simple mistake which created these numeric impostures.

LINK TO IMAGE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/grZiu.png

Comment: Which numbers, exactly, are you talking about?

Comment: Probably they are some other numerals provided in some bizarre Unicode block, and they are not recognized by `atof` (actually, I doubt that `atof` is even UTF-8 aware). How did you create them?

Comment: Copy-and-paste text into your question directly instead of posting an image of text. An image of text is not easily parseable, reusable, or accessible.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: And it's likely that with copy-and-pasted text, we could actually diagnose the problem.

Comment: Maybe the first digit of each number changed from digit `1` to letter `l`.

Comment: Here's copy paste.  I wish I could make it cleaner:

Scott-Jaromins-MacBook-Pro:HW1 scottjaromin$ ./a.out 10.3 19.2 17.6
argv: 10.3
10.3
argv: 19.2
19.2
argv: 17.6
17.6
1239.6
Scott-Jaromins-MacBook-Pro:HW1 scottjaromin$ ./a.out l0.3 l9.2 l7.6
argv: l0.3
0
argv: l9.2
0
argv: l7.6
0
0
Scott-Jaromins-MacBook-Pro:HW1 scottjaromin$ ./a.out l0.3 l9.2 l7.6

Comment: Also, I'm wondering how I made them.  I didn't use any copy and paste.  I really am feeling paranoid right now.  Things don't happen for no reason on computers.

Answer (score 1):

> If no valid conversion could be performed, the function returns zero (0.0).

Source - [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)

This seems to be happening for some reason..

Like the link suggests, you might want to try [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) instead.

---

It looks like the `1`s are replaced, somehow, by `l`s as @aschepler suggests

Comment: No, the problem is that somehow those numbers returning 0.0 aren't real numbers.  If you look closely, they have a different font.  I don't know how I made them, and that is the question.

And whoever changed the title to "AtoF is broken" completely misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @Thumbz Ah, ok, thats clearer, perhaps aschepler is onto something then, `1` -> `l`

Comment: Yeah, I just tried them out, and it appears it is an 'l'.  What I don't get, though, is how it happened.  L is under a different hand, under a different finger than I'd even use 1 handed.  The best I can think is I somehow switched hands in my head and hit with by right ring instead of left, but... I dunno.

If this is a troll, it's a damn good one.  Incredibly confusing bug, makes me look like an ass, so simple it's scary.

Comment: @Thumbz: I just rolled back the modification of the title.